# Syslog multiple facilities using python

Tags: python, logging, syslog, error-logging

I would like my python program to log to multiple facilities (`LOCALX`), where each facility entry would be for a particular condition.  For example, all logging of network traffic between X and program go to `LOCAL0`, and between Y and the program to `LOCAL1`.

Anyways, I can do this quite easily with python's logging mechanism: I would import `logging`, and create a `Sysloghandler` for each facility and add it to one or more loggers.

But python also has a `syslog` module.  I wish to use this module instead since almost all of the other python code I'm contributing to uses `syslog`.  Is it possible and how?

The `syslog` documents suggest that this can't be done.

I am using python 2.7

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `syslog` module documentation specifies that the `facility` can be set as an optional keyword argument to [`syslog.openlog([ident[, logoption[, facility]]])`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/syslog.html#syslog.openlog):

> The optional `facility` keyword argument (default is `LOG_USER`) sets the default facility for messages which do not have a facility explicitly encoded.

You can also encode the `facility` in each message, as stated in the documentation of [`syslog.syslog(priority, message)`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/syslog.html#syslog.syslog):

> Each message is tagged with a priority composed of a facility and a level. The optional priority argument, which defaults to `LOG_INFO`, determines the message priority. If the facility is not encoded in priority using logical-or (`LOG_INFO | LOG_USER`), the value given in the `openlog()` call is used.

Comment: I guess I overlooked that logically or'ing of priority and facility.  This really helps alot.  Thanks a million.